# Why does size always = 4096 in Linux character driver read call?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've been working my way through the Linux char driver examples on the web but run across a behavior that I can't explain.

```
static ssize_t my_read(struct file *f, char __user *user_buf, size_t cnt, loff_t* off)
{
   printk( KERN_INFO "Read called for %zd bytes\n", cnt );
   return cnt;
}
```

The message always indicates that `cnt=4096` bytes regardless of what the number of bytes specified in the user space call to read (e.g..

```
[11043.021789] Read called for 4096 bytes
```

However, the user space read calls

```
retval = fread(_rx_buffer, sizeof(char), 5, file_ptr);
printf( "fread returned %d bytes\n", retval );
```

The output from user space is

```
fread returned 5 bytes.
```

How is it that the value of the size in `my_read` is always 4096 but the value from `fread` indicates 5 ?  I know there's something I'm missing but not sure what...

Comment: Could this be readahead into an intermediate buffer with page granularity (4096 is a very widely used page size in CPU configuration), or maybe the hard disk's block size (512 for older, 4096 for newer, multi TB drives)? Did you try what happens when calling for, say, 9345 bytes?

Comment: It looks that way.  If I ask for 10, 20, or 4096 bytes via user space, I see "Read called for 4096 bytes" in the logfile.  If I asked for 4097 bytes via user space, I see two new entries of "Read called for 4096 bytes" in the logfile.  Asking for 9345 results in two entries in the logfile, "Read called for 8192 bytes" and "Read called for 4096 bytes".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) (in `unistd.h`) and it should output 5 characters. When using libc ([`fread(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread), `fwrite(3)`, etc.), you're using the internal libc buffer, which is usually the size of a page (which is almost always 4 kiB).

I believe that the first time you call `fread()` for 5 bytes, libc does an internal `read()` of 4096 bytes and the following `fread()` will simply return bytes libc already has in the buffer associated with the `FILE` structure you use. Until you reach 4096. The 4097th byte will issue another `read` of 4096 bytes and so on.

This also happens when you write, for example when using `printf()`, which is just `fprintf()` with `stdout()` as its first argument. libc won't call `write(2)` directly, but put your stuff in its internal buffer instead (also of 4096 bytes). It will flush if you call

```c
fflush(stdout);
```

yourself, or anytime it finds the byte 0x0a (newline in ASCII) within the bytes sent.

Try it, you shall see:

```c
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for sleep() */

int main(void) {
    printf("the following message won't show up\n");
    printf("hello, world!");
    sleep(3);
    printf("\nuntil now...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This will work however (not using libc's buffering):

```c
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for sleep(), write(), and STDOUT_FILENO */

int main(void) {
    printf("the following message WILL show up\n");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "hello!", 6);
    sleep(3);
    printf("see?\n");

    return 0;
}
```

`STDOUT_FILENO` is the default file descriptor for the standard output (1).

Flushing every time there's a newline is essential for the user of a terminal to see messages instantly, and is also helpful for per-line processing, which is done a lot in a Unix environment.

So, even if libc uses `read()` and `write()` syscalls directly to fill and flush its buffers (and by the way the Microsoft implementation of the C standard library must be using Windows stuff, probably [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) and `WriteFile`), those syscalls absolutely do not know libc. This leads to interesting behaviours when using both:

```c
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for write() and STDOUT_FILENO */

int main(void) {
    printf("1. first message (flushed now)\n");
    printf("2. second message (without flushing)");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "3. third message (flushed now)", 30);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
1. first message (flushed now)
3. third message (flushed now)2. second message (without flushing)
```

(third before second!).

Also, note that you can turn off libc's buffering with [`setvbuf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf). Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h> /* for setvbuf() and printf() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for sleep() */

int main(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("the following message WILL show up\n");
    printf("hello!");
    sleep(3);
    printf("see?\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I never tried, but I guess you could do the same with the `FILE*` you get when `fopen()`ing your character device and disable I/O buffering for this one:

```c
FILE* fh = fopen("/dev/my-char-device", "rb");
setvbuf(fh, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Comment: +1 - however is the `write` guaranteed to flush libc buffer for `printf`? I always thought that it goes directly to kernel syscall but I cannot find in specification any information regarding the behaviour.

Comment: `write` doesn't know libc. I will add an example to my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: I figured it had to have something to do with buffering but didn't understand enough to know why this was occurring (and more specifically how to be able to request a specific # of bytes).  Excellent explanation! Thanks.

Comment: `write(0, "hello!", 6);` writes to standard *input*, not standard output. `STDOUT_FILENO` is **1**.